# How Can I loop on all received signal data in Canoe using Capl?

Tags: capl, canoe, canalyzer

Lets say I have a message called msg1 which contains many signal (sig1,sig2,sig3,......sig20) with initial value 0,
How can I loop on all the received signal data using capl and print the signals name that has fired or its value is changed from 0 to 1?

Answer (score 0):

Withn a loop, `snpritf` the names and use `getSignal` to get the value.
For details, refer to the CAPL help for getSignal, scroll down to the very bottom and expand the collapsebox for "Special Use Case". Vector hid that well...